# Missunderstanding CSV format

Tags: c#, csv

First of all, I wanna say: "I know there're XML/JSON/YAML formats, and I know how they works". But now I'm facing a task to make export to `CSV` format file.

I've read about CSV on wikipedia, searched StackOverflow on CSV topics, and didn't find answer.

As I read, this is popular format for future Excel tables display.
Okay, if I have a simple class with only `ValueType` properties, it's just fine.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ToCsvString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0};{1}", ID, Name);
    }

    public static MyClass FromCsvString(string source)
    {
        var parts = source.Split(';');

        var id = int.Parse(parts[0]);
        var name = parts[1];

        return new MyClass()
        {
            ID = id,
            Name = name,
        };
    }
}
```

But what if I have a little bit more complex class. For example with `List<>` of other objects.

```
public class MyClassWithList: MyClass
{
    public MyClassWithList()
    {
        ItemsList = new List<string>();
    }
    public List<string> ItemsList { get; set; }

    public string ToCsvString()
    {
        // How to format it for future according to CSV format?
        return string.Format("{0};{1}", base.ToCsvString(), ItemsList.ToString());
    }

    public static MyClassWithList FromCsvString(string source)
    {
        var parts = source.Split(';');

        var id = int.Parse(parts[0]);
        var name = parts[1];
        // How to get it back from CSV formatted string?
        var itemsList = parts[2];

        return new MyClassWithList()
            {
                ID = id,
                Name = name,
                ItemsList = new List<string>()
            };
    }
}
```

How should I serialize/deserialize it to `CSV`?
And final question is how to do the same about when class `A` contains class `B` instances?

Comment: There are many ways to get CSV handling wrong. However, there are a number of free libraries available that do this, and do it well. I don't see any advantage to reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: Depends on what you want that CSV to look like.  Define the format you want to export to, then you can write the code to export it.

Comment: @David as I wrote, that's not my wish to make import/export to csv. That's just I have to do for other people. I've seen the nuget in C# calles csvhelper. 
I also read wikipedia's article about csv. But I'm here to understand how this kind of problem about "List<>" to csv.

Comment: csv format is really built for flat tabular data.  If you need to format hierarchical data, which is what you are doing by adding classes within classes, you might want to look at a format that better suits your needs like json or xml.

Comment: Your question needs better detail.  As it is right now, it almost sounds like you're trying to store class information, instead of flat data.  That's far from what CSV is ideally suited for.  You'd do much better looking into storing the class as XML or JSON.  Each column in a CSV must be well defined; once it is, knowing how to get your data should be fairly simple.

Comment: @KamikyIT: `"that's not my wish to make import/export to csv"` - Then it's not clear at all to me what you're asking.  If you *don't want* to export to CSV, then what *do* you want to do?  Please clarify.

Comment: @Fran ok, as u say, CSV cannot resolve this issue about multiple "child" objects, right? And yes, I know XML/JSON formats, and I also know about they will get it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you have to flatten your data.

If ClassA contains a ClassB, then you'll need to create a flattened POCO that has properties that access any nested properties, e.g. ClassB_PropertyA.

You can really only have 1 variable length property and it has to be the last property, then you can have any column after a point represent a single list property.

Secondly, there is no CSV Serliazation standard. There is https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt but that only deals with reading text from fields. Something as simple as changing your locale can mess up a CSV library as semicolons will be switched for commas in cultures where a common represents a decimal. There are also many bugs and edge cases in Excel that cause serialization to String to be problematic. And some data is automatically converted to Dates or Times. You need to determine which program you expect to open the CSV and learn about how it handles CSV data.

Once you have a flat POCO, then a CSV is simply a header row with the name of each property followed by a row per object. There are libraries that can help you with this.

Comment: @KamikyIT you will definitely need to escape your strings if you will have commas in them. (Or semicolon, CSV is localized!)

Comment: "Secondly, there is no CSV standard" How about RFC 4180?

Comment: @Novaterata yes, I understood this problem from the begining. That's why I started this topic.

Comment: @aquinas Updated. I meant in regards to serialization. In my experience the standard is not very real once Excel is involved